# Save shell output to variable

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

I am trying to compress a jpg with `mogrify` (GraphicsMagicks) and i need to store the result in a variable.

```
$compressed_jpg_content = shell_exec("gm mogrify -quality 85 - < ".escapeshellarg($image_path)." $filename.jpg");
    if (!$compressed_jpg_content) {
        throw new Exception("Conversion to compressed JPG failed");
    }
```

However its not working and i get `Conversion to compressed JPG failed` and i think there is a problem with my command

**Edit**

Thanks to **Allen Butler**

In this case `$image_path` is actually a POST variable and `$filename` is `I4tWX0HI.jpg`

Error : `gm mogrify: Unable to open file (I4tWX0HI.jpg)`

The error is pretty obvious since `I4tWX0HI.jpg` does not exist yet.That being said , how can i modify the command to make it put the content in the variable instead of trying to open a file

Regards

Comment: You could try appending `2>&1` to the end of your command to convert standard error to standard out and echo out `compressed_jpg_content` to see that error for debugging. Try `$compressed_jpg_content = shell_exec("gm mogrify -quality 85 - < .escapeshellarg($image_path)." $filename.jpg 2>&1"); echo $compressed_jpg_content;`

Comment: @AllenButler check edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the gm mogrify manual, if overwrites the original file with the new image so you can not specify the target image on the command line.

You can try one of the following options:

1) Hope that if mogrify ready from STDIN, it will output to STDOUT. Can not test it so it is a guest. You will notice that you skip the output file in that case:

```
$compressed_jpg_content = shell_exec("gm mogrify -quality 85 - < ".escapeshellarg($image_path));
```

b) Let mogrify change the image (ignore the filename you have) and read the image data afterwards:

```
$compressed_jpg_content = shell_exec("gm mogrify -quality 85 ".escapeshellarg($image_path)." && cat ".escapeshellarg($image_path));
```

c) If you don't want to change the original file, copy it before:

```
$tmpfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "image_");
copy($image, $tmpfile);
shell_exec("gm mogrify -quality 85 ".escapeshellarg(tmpfile));
$compressed_jpg_content = file_get_contents($tmpfile);
unlink($tmpfile);
```

Comment: Option b worked fine.How will the command change if `$image_path` is a BMP and i want to convert it to jpg

Comment: You have to use the -format option to set to jpg. Mogrify will then output to the same filename where the .bmp file extension.is replaced by .jpg.